# Heroku gives a server error for my API but no error code

Tags: heroku, internal-server-error

Here is the log I receive when I send a GET request.

```
2021-03-14T08:05:34.522724+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/courses" host=shielded-meadow-94057.herokuapp.com request_id=0ff2b784-7dcc-421c-ae29-46ee9cc442ff fwd="73.222.178.14" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=52ms status=500 bytes=851 protocol=https
```

The only error I get is

```
GET https://shielded-meadow-94057.herokuapp.com/api/courses 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Can you please share a way to fix it and receive my data?

Comment: Check the logs of your Heroku application to see more details. You can stream the log using the Heroku CLI after logging in:- "heroku logs -t"

Comment: Well, the log does not really give me an error, and I do not think it is an error but more like something changed on Heroku's side that my application code is no longer following compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out I had to set the correct SSL flag for Heroku.

```
const pg = require('pg');
pg.default.ssl = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
```